# How to branch/copy/move folder to different projects and keep history in TFS?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I have a folder underneath Project A that I would like to instead have under Project B, and I would like to retain the folder history once it is under Project B.

And, what I really want is to have the current state of Project A folder branched to a Dev branch under Project B, and *then* a snapshot through an older changeset of the Project A folder branched to a Main branch under Project B.  For example:

`$/TfsProjectA/MyProject` --> branched to `$/TfsProjectB/MyProject/Dev` with full history
and then since if I have the full history I could do
`$/TfsProjectB/MyProject/Dev` --> branch to `$/TfsProjectB/MyProject/Main` based on a previous version of the now `$/TfsProjectB/MyProject/Dev`

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's  impossible.

Branching/move will **lost the folder history** , but the individual file history is actually not lost. It is hidden under the little "expand me" arrow at the far left on a file history line. Expand it on the oldest history entry for a file, or anywhere you see it, and you will see history of that individual file also from an old location that no longer exists.

However, merge the branch of changeset is **based on the folder history.** Such as the first changeset of `$/TfsProjectB/MyProject/Dev` will be changeset XXX branched from   `$/TfsProjectA/MyProject`.

You will not be able to select the older changeset of  `$/TfsProjectA/MyProject`

---

**Solution**

A way to achieve what your need is directly merge `$/TfsProjectA/MyProject` with old changeset to `$/TfsProjectB/MyProject/Main`  Even though you will get a warning prompt as below:

> A merge relationship does not exist between the source and the target.
>   A **baseless merge will be performed**.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I did run into the baseless merge on my first try and that works, but I have to manually change the target branch each time and was hoping to avoid it. What I think I'll do is do the baseless merges for now, and when I get to a point where I can take a snapshot of the "new" Dev branch and branch that to a "real" Main, do that and then I think things should be happy from that point on.